# Controlling Quest 2 VR Headset with Third Party App : Interacting with Menus and Buttons

Tags: mobile, bluetooth, simulation, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I'm currently working on a project where we aim to control certain aspects of the Quest 2 VR headset using a mobile phone. Specifically, we want to interact with menus and buttons on the headset without requiring the full capabilities of the Quest 2 controller.

We would most certainly be connected via Bluetooth or at least try to simulate a bluetooth connection.

I've looked into the Oculus API and related resources, but I haven't found a solution that fits our needs. Can anyone provide insights or guidance on whether this is possible and how to approach it?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I went ahead and looked through the different possibilities that came to my mind, Oculus API mainly. I also tried connecting a mouse and a keyboard via Bluetooth to the headset, those worked but only on the main Quest 2 menu and official apps, they became obsolete once i launched an app. The idea may be to extend the mouse and keyboard possibilities by forcing the different apps to accepts its inputs ?